# How to get line number in excel sheet using python?

Tags: python, xlrd

I have an Excel sheet like this:

```
  A B C D E F G
1 0 0 0
2   0 0
3 0
4
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0   0
```

And every '0' represents some data values, I am reading the values and comparing them with my original data, when the data match fails it returns a message. What I want is to return the line number of excel sheet as well as the column number or particularly the CELL location.  Please help me doing this!

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: if you are comparing cell values then you have their index which is line number and column number, otherwise you can start counter on row and column loop with increment on every iteration, this will tell you exact column number and row number.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('book.xls')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            print "row::::: ", row
            print "column:: ", column
            print "value::: ", sheet.cell(row,column).value
```

It will give you exact `row`, `column` numbers and `cell` value

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the column and row while iterating over the worksheet. An `xlrd` `Cell` does not keep track of where they 'live' in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

if you are comparing cell values then you have their index which is line number and column number, otherwise you can start counter on row and column loop with increment on every iteration, this will tell you exact column number and row number.