# how can I read each line of a xls file with pausing

Tags: python

I have a xls file on my desktop in mac which has many row (each row consists of a word). what I want is to show each line for 3 minutes in terminal.
note that the version of xls is the 2016.

Thanks to [How to get line number in excel sheet using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541641/how-to-get-line-number-in-excel-sheet-using-python)

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
# at first I try to know how many rows and how many columns I have 
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xls')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            print "row::::: ", row
            print "column:: ", column
            print "value::: ", sheet.cell(row,column).value

# then I read my file in 
df = pd.read_excel(path + filename)
```

Then I know that I can use something like below to

```
import time
print("something")
time.sleep(5.5)    # pause 5.5 seconds
print("something")
```

But I could not figure out how to do it without write print , any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it in this way on Mac

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd
# at first I try to know how many rows and how many columns I have 
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xls')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            os.system('clear')
            print "value::: ", sheet.cell(row,column).value
            time.sleep(5.5)    # pause 5.5 seconds
```

Comment: thanks , I asked another question, if you have an idea please shoot here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676234/how-to-make-a-loop-over-and-over-until-we-stop-or-pause-it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, your problem is that you want a line to show up on the terminal for some time, but get hidden when the next one shows up. You can try this for `python3` (see the accepted answer for earlier versions):

```
import time
import subprocess

import pandas as pd
import xlrd
# at first I try to know how many rows and how many columns I have 
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xls')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            subprocess.run(["clear"])
            print "row::::: ", row
            print "column:: ", column
            print "value::: ", sheet.cell(row,column).value
            time.sleep(5.5)    # pause 5.5 seconds
```

`clear` is generally for Unix though, if it does not work on a Mac, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198377/how-to-clear-previous-output-in-terminal-in-mac-os-x) can be helpful.

Comment: I got this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_prog.py", line 10, in <module>
    subprocess.run(["clear"])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: I liked your answer, thanks  but I get error with it

Comment: Yeah, sry, I forgot to mention, but `subprocess.run` is actually the preferred way to call external subprocesses (like shell commands) in `python3`. In earlier versions, like `python2.7` (which you probably use), `os.system` is applicable, as suggested above.

Comment: thanks , I asked another question, if you have an idea please shoot here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676234/how-to-make-a-loop-over-and-over-until-we-stop-or-pause-it