# What is actually being counted when I pass an excel file to python code that counts lines in a file?

Tags: python, excel

I used the following questions as sources, listed along with the code I am asking about:

---

1. [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

   ```
   def file_len(fname):
       with open(fname) as f:
           for i, l in enumerate(f):
               pass
       return i + 1

   fname = '/path/file.xls'
   file_len(fname)
   ```

This returned 40, when the actual number of lines is 56.

---

2. [How to count rows in multiple csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320868/how-to-count-rows-in-multiple-csv-file)

   ```
   import glob
   import pandas as pd

   files = glob.glob('files/*.xls')

   d = {f: sum(1 for line in open(f)) for f in files}
   ```

This returned 40 for the same file as well, and did not return the correct counts for other files in that path either.

---

It is not returning an error, and returns the same count consistently across methods, however it is not the correct number of lines.

My question is : What is actually being counted in the .xls files, since it is not the number of lines?

Comment: Define number of lines, do you only have 40 lines that has data and just blank lines inbetween? Can you show what your file looks like ?

Comment: How do you figure the "actual number of lines" is 56?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541641/how-to-get-line-number-in-excel-sheet-using-python

Comment: There are 56 rows in the spreadsheet, 9 columns, and no blank cells.  None of the other files have blank space either.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What I mean by 'actual number' is when I open the file in open office, there are 56 rows. My question is where does the 40 come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xls is not a text format, it's binary. There are apparently a number of bytes in the file that are equivalent to the ASCII newline character, but that will have no relation to how many rows there are in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, it was very helpful.